# Open in new tab on right click menu was disable in IE while link has javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have 2 links on menu bar, one with javascript has right click menu issue on IE, open in new tab was disabled in 2nd one, please see describe as below, any settings in IE can fix this?

1. work

   `<a href="/site/home">home</a>`
2. not work, open in new tab is disabled

   `<a href="javascript:goto(this,'/site/home');">home</a>`

Comment: I think you would need to change your JS to modify the `href` attribute of the link instead and then it'll work. e.g. `$('#home-link').prop('href', '/site/home')` or however you want to target the links. Browser may not allow opening `javascript:` protocol links in new tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in IE11. Instead, change your script to modify the `href` of the anchor tag and the browser will see a valid link that it can open instead of a `javascript:` protocol link (which does work in Chrome/Edge anyway).

This example just shows a clean way to target route links and insert a href link. You can do it however you prefer.

```js
// vanilla JS
document.getElementById('home-link').href = "https://google.com";

// jQuery data attribute routes example
var routes = {
  "home": "https://google.com"
}

$("a[data-route]").each(function () {
  var $a = $(this),
      route = $a.data("route");
  
  $a.prop('href', routes[route]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">Normal Link</a></li>
  <li><a id="home-link">Vanilla JS Link</a></li>
  <li><a data-route="home">jQuery Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks @subkamran. I know why I was using a-href with javascript, I migrated code from `<td name="leftnav_home_home" id="leftnav_home_home" class="submenu" onclick="Form_goto(this, '/project/home');">Overview</td>`, but it's for td, and it didn't have any open in tab* options for it. So I removed javascript from my code.

Comment: I assume you meant "doesn't work in Chrome/Edge"